# Countup timer with three different intervals

Tags: javascript, html

I am to create a website that shows different time intervals. I wrote the code but it is not displaying when i open it in my browser.
Here is the code.
I would like to drop the code the same way it is in my text editor (sublime text 3)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>timer</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // GRAB TIMER-DISPLAY ELEMENT
let timerDisplay =  document.getElementsByClassName( 'timerDisplay')[0];

// TIMER DATA
const myFootballMatch = {
  'firstHalf' : { 
    'start' : 0,
    'end' : 4.5
  },
  
  'interval' : { 
    'start' : 0,
    'end' : 1.5
  },
  
  'secondHalf' : { 
    'start' : 4.5,
    'end' : 9
  }
};

// THE FUNCTION
const runTimer = (timerObject, timerId = 0) => {

   // EXIT FUNCTION IF THERE ARE NO MORE TIMERS
   if (parseInt(timerId) === Object.keys(timerObject).length) {
     return;
   }

  let timerName = Object.keys(timerObject)[timerId];
  let timerCount = parseFloat(timerObject[timerName]['start']);
  let timerEnd = parseFloat(timerObject[timerName]['end']);
  
  const timer = setInterval(() => {
  
    timerCount = timerCount + 0.01;
    
    if (timerName === 'interval') {
      timerDisplay.textContent = '4.50';
    }
    
    else {
      timerDisplay.textContent = timerCount.toFixed(2);
    }
  
    if (timerCount > (timerEnd - 0.01)) {
  
      clearInterval(timer);
      runTimer(myFootballMatch, timerId + 1);
    }
  }, 10);
}

// RUN THE FUNCTION
runTimer(myFootballMatch);
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .timerDisplay {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 96px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="timerDisplay"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code. Anytime I open it on my browser (chrome), it returns an empty page. Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the DOM is not ready when you are assigning `timerDisplay`. The easiest solution is to wait for the window to finish loading by listening to the `window`'s `onload` event.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>timer</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', () => {   // <====== Wait for the window to finish loading
        // GRAB TIMER-DISPLAY ELEMENT
        let timerDisplay =  document.getElementsByClassName( 'timerDisplay')[0];
        
        // TIMER DATA
        const myFootballMatch = {
          'firstHalf' : { 
            'start' : 0,
            'end' : 4.5
          },
          
          'interval' : { 
            'start' : 0,
            'end' : 1.5
          },
          
          'secondHalf' : { 
            'start' : 4.5,
            'end' : 9
          }
        };
        
        // THE FUNCTION
        const runTimer = (timerObject, timerId = 0) => {
        
           // EXIT FUNCTION IF THERE ARE NO MORE TIMERS
           if (parseInt(timerId) === Object.keys(timerObject).length) {
             return;
           }
        
          let timerName = Object.keys(timerObject)[timerId];
          let timerCount = parseFloat(timerObject[timerName]['start']);
          let timerEnd = parseFloat(timerObject[timerName]['end']);
          
          const timer = setInterval(() => {
          
            timerCount = timerCount + 0.01;
            
            if (timerName === 'interval') {
              timerDisplay.textContent = '4.50';
            }
            
            else {
              timerDisplay.textContent = timerCount.toFixed(2);
            }
          
            if (timerCount > (timerEnd - 0.01)) {
          
              clearInterval(timer);
              runTimer(myFootballMatch, timerId + 1);
            }
          }, 10);
        }
        
        // RUN THE FUNCTION
        runTimer(myFootballMatch);
    });
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
    .timerDisplay {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 96px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="timerDisplay"></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please can you help me out with the timer. The timer shows in seconds and milliseconds, is there anyway I can make it to show only minutes and second

Comment: What does `timerCount` represent? If the value is `4.5` does that mean 4.5 seconds, or 4.5 minutes? Since javascript handles time in milliseconds, I would recommend that you keep all your time variables in milliseconds, and only convert them when they are to be displayed.

Comment: please can you show me how to convert the time variables to minutes. I've been having serious issues trying to do that. Can you please show me the way around it with respect to the previous code

Answer (score 0):

On the other hand, your console is displaying errors and is telling you what's wrong. Open it. You are running your JS code before the HTML is loaded, so `getElementsByClassName('timerDisplay')` can't find anything, it returns `null`, and `null[0]` throws an error in the console. Place your script at the end of the `<body>`.